# What is a First Order Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

If a word conforms to a special rule I call it a First Order Word™

| First Order™ | Not First Order™ |
| --- | --- |
| Worry | Worried |
| Typo | Correct |
| Rye | Wheat |
| Rip | Ripped |
| Tow | Towed |
| Rot | Fresh |
| Weep | Cheer |
| Were | Are |
| You | Me |
| Pout | Smile |

The CSV version:

```
First Order™, Not First Order™
Worry, Worried
Typo, Correct
Rye, Wheat
Rip, Ripped
Tow, Towed
Rot, Fresh
Weep, Cheer
Were, Are
You, Me
Pout, Smile
```

Can you tell me what the rule is?

**Bonus:**

> Prove yourself you know the rule by telling me Second Order™ words

Comment: TYPEWRITER vs COMPUTER should be one.

Comment: That's a good one @William Nathanael

Comment: No Third Order words are allowed :(

Comment: TYPEWRITER is the longest first row word possible, probably would have have instantly given the puzzle away.

Comment: @Brisingr How about POWERTRIPPER?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A first order word is one that

> can be typed using the first row on a QWERTY keyboard.

Which would mean that examples of second order words would be

> Sad
> Shall
> Gas
> Half
> Flag